# WCF REST WebInvoke POST returns bad response

Tags: vb.net, wcf

May anybody help me I am tired of doing all the thing, but service returns bad return if string length exceeds more than 10000 characters.

Thanks.

This is my `.svc` file:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="VB" Debug="true" Service="BPMMobile" 
    CodeBehind="~/App_Code/BPMMobile.svc.vb"  Factory="MyServiceHostFactory" %>
```

My contract:

```
<OperationContract()> _
   <WebInvoke(UriTemplate:="/SaveData?
Data={Data}", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, Method:="POST", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml)> _
    Function SaveData(Data As String) As String
```

Here is my `web.config` file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MobileBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"  />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
   </bindings>

   <services>
      <service name="BPMMobile">
        <endpoint 
            behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" 
            binding="webHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="MobileBinding" 
            contract="IBPMMobile" />
      </service>
      <service name="DMSService">
        <endpoint 
            behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" 
            binding="webHttpBinding" 
            contract="IDMSService" />
    </service>
    <service name="ImportMaster">
        <endpoint 
            behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"
            binding="webHttpBinding" 
            contract="IImportMaster"  />
    </service>
   </services>
   <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>`
```

**Here is my Custom service host**

```
Public Class MyServiceHost
Inherits WebServiceHost
Public Sub New()
End Sub

Public Sub New(singletonInstance As Object, ParamArray baseAddresses As Uri())
    MyBase.New(singletonInstance, baseAddresses)
End Sub

Public Sub New(serviceType As Type, ParamArray baseAddresses As Uri())
    MyBase.New(serviceType, baseAddresses)
End Sub


Protected Overrides Sub OnOpening()
    MyBase.OnOpening()

    If MyBase.Description IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each endpoint In MyBase.Description.Endpoints
            Dim transport = endpoint.Binding.CreateBindingElements().Find(Of TransportBindingElement)()
            If transport IsNot Nothing Then
                transport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 5242880
                transport.MaxBufferPoolSize = 5242880
                transport.MaxBufferPoolSize = 5242880
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

```
Class MyWebServiceHostFactory
Inherits WebServiceHostFactory
Protected Overrides Function CreateServiceHost(serviceType As Type, baseAddresses As Uri()) As ServiceHost
    Return New MyServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses)
End Function
```

End Class

```
Public NotInheritable Class MyServiceHostFactory
Inherits System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory
Public Overrides Function CreateServiceHost(constructorString As String, baseAddresses As Uri()) As System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase
    Return MyBase.CreateServiceHost(constructorString, baseAddresses)
End Function

Protected Overrides Function CreateServiceHost(serviceType As Type, baseAddresses As Uri()) As System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost
    Return New MyServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses)
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: You appear to be using a custom service host factory - please post the code; at a guess you may not be using the binding configuration you think you are.

Comment: Your method is POST! Why you are sending data in query string? Use XMl and JSON for large data.

Comment: @Tim I have post my custom service host factory.please do needfull help.thanks

Comment: @Tim I have updated custom service host factory, IF you have any idea please share it with me.Thanks in advance.